# Употребление глагола «предполагаться»

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

> Параллельно с ними [подключенными приборами] **предполагается** подключить электрообогреватель.

Корректно ли такое безличное употребление глагола «предполагаться»? Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Характерное для проектной документации слово подразумевает в первую очередь то, что эта позиция с подключаемыми приборами **предполагается проектом** или изменениями в проекте, и, следовательно, вполне корректно.

Вызывает сомнение слово *подключить* как глагол, в этой связке (*предполагается подключить*) выражающей необязательность решения, более свойственное текстам концепции. Правильнее будет употребление существительного: *предполагается подключение*.

Comment: Проектом обычно "предусмотрено/предусматривается" (что-то статичное); "предполагается" (планируется) людьми (что сделать? - подключить, напр. в ближайшем будущем, когда упомянутый прибор купят).

Comment: В предложенной фразе — вне контекста — вложенного смысла не понять. Если действительно о житейских делах идёт разговор, то такое «планирование нагрузок на сеть» хозяевам выйдет боком.